# hive hashing for a/b testing

Tags: hadoop, hash, hive, md5

I am trying to convert the hashing process from MySql to hive. In hive my code fails with below error

```
 ParseException line 6:7 cannot recognize input near '0xffffff' '>' '50' in expression specificati
```

How to do in write the hex number 0xffffff in hive

MySQL Code(got the MySQL logic from this reference http://blog.richardweiss.org/2016/12/25/hash-splits.html:

```
SELECT if(
   conv(
      substr(
          md5(concat(ID, '-', SALT)),
          1, 6),
      16, 10)/0xffffff > CONTROL_GROUP_SIZE, 't', 'c')
```

Hive code:

```
SELECT if(
   conv(
      substr(
          md5(concat('12345', '-','xxx2017')),
          1, 6),
      16,10)/0xffffff > 50, 't', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not recognize the hexadecimal representation, starting `0x`,like in Python. So, simply use `'ffffff'` instead. Also, since you are essentially doing a decimal division, you could add another `conv` function to convert it to decimal.

```
SELECT if(
   conv(
      substr(
          md5(concat('12345', '-','xxx2017')),
          1, 6),
      16,10)/conv('ffffff',16,10) > 50, 't', 'c')
```